# addEventListener stops code in timer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, addeventlistener

I have two blue squares that appear and disappear with the click of the * key. One click has a timer on it. The code works the first time around, but the second time it stops working. In debugger it stopped on the line

```
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerB);
```

Not really sure why it works the first time, but not the second time.

```
var onOff:Boolean = false;


// Off Timer
var timer:Timer = new Timer(300);

function timerA(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    blue1.visible = false;
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerB);
    timer.start();
}

function timerB(event:TimerEvent):void {
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerB);
    timer.stop();
    blue2.visible = false;
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,turnoff);

function turnoff(event:KeyboardEvent):void { 
    if (event.keyCode == 106) {
        if (onOff == false) {
            timerA(null);
            onOff = true;
        } else if (onOff == true) {
            blue1.visible = true;
            blue2.visible = true;
            onOff = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain exactly what behaviour are you looking for to get from this? Everything seems to work as expected. Is there a reason why `timerA`-function has `event:KeyboardEvent` as a parameter?

Comment: You need explain a bit more about how it "doesn't work".   Are you getting an error? Unexpected behavior?  Please edit your question and explain exactly what is (or isn't) happening, and the expected behavior.

Comment: Vesper actually did figure this out. Thanks for your help, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who did `timer = null;` in `TimerB()`? There goes your timer. You should instead call `timer.stop()`.

Comment: No, sorry. I had made a few changes doing tests of my own, and now that I've put it back the original way, this does work. Thanks.